# Why isn't the Death Star's structure radial?

Tags: star-wars

The Death Star is large enough to have its own gravitational field. One would expect that the preferred "down" direction points toward its center, instead of running from pole to pole. However, the pictures of the incomplete station show a structure that favors two perpendicular directions. How come?

Comment: Suppose gravity pointed toward the center.  Would it get weaker as you moved "down"?  If so, it would be strange for people to feel their weight change as they move between levels.  If not, there will be some sort of singularity near the center, and people on the inner levels will feel strange lateral forces.  It would seem the most comfortable for gravity to have the same direction and magnitude everywhere, especially for personnel who are used to living on large planets.  And as James Sheridan's answer suggests, this is attainable with period technology.

Comment: (And now I'm imagining a Death Star on which everyone suffers from chronic vertigo, a la [Lucille Two](http://arresteddevelopment.wikia.com/wiki/Lucille_Austero).)

Comment: Whether it is "large enough" is irrelevant, the requirement is that it's *massive enough*.

Comment: From a structural engineering standpoint, wouldn't that necessitate the entire station have curved walkways?  Doesn't sound too comfortable to me...

Comment: @NateEldredge FWIW gravity generally does get weaker as you move toward the center of a sphere - at least, there's no gravity right in the middle.

Comment: Why build the Death Star in a spherical shape at all, rather than a big cube?

Comment: Since the Star Wars universe apparently has control over gravity (i.e. even on small ships like the Millenium Falcon, people walk around on the floor), the natural gravity of the death star could be overcome by local gravity generators.

Comment: @RobertF you're right, 'why a spherical shape if not radial', is actually the better question.  Everything that has mass has a gravitational field, but you need a lot of mass to force the material to be spherical.  The death star doesn't have that much.  So then why spherical?  Well, it's a stable shape to build.  Also, it just looks cool. And who doesn't want their weapon of terror to look cool?

Comment: @RobertF because a cube could never be mistaken for a moon, thus depriving society of one of the most quoted lines from the SWU.

Comment: @RobertF: Because that allows for a maximum of internal volume at a minimum of external surface area maybe?

Comment: President to Astronomer: what's the new moon we appear to have gained; Astronomer to President: I'm sorry sir, I don't know; President to Astronomer: what do you mean you don't know; Astronomer to President: wait a minute, that's no moon!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A radial structure would give the floors and ceilings a noticable curvature, which would get more pronounced closer to the interior. Flat objects, like regular furniture, wouldn't be flush with the ground: all of their weight would be carried by their centre, with the edges sticking out above the floor (or, more accurately, the floor would stick out under the edges).

Not only would this require expensive custom furniture and equipment, but the curvature on inner levels would be greater than the outer levels, so equipment would only sit properly within a particular range of levels.

"Local flatness", eg. per room, wouldn't work either:

- Items nearer the walls would roll towards the centre, which is technically "down hill"
- The layout of rooms on each level would have to depend on those above and below it, to avoid floors and ceilings "pinching" together.
- Alternatively, some extra space could be allocated to allow for pinching (eg. with adjustable floor/ceiling tiles on pistons), but this reduces the number of levels that can fit in the structure.
- Floor plans couldn't be revised by simply moving walls around: the floors would need to be altered and walls from one place might not fit in another.
- There would be abrupt changes between the sections, eg. at doors and along corridors.
- Large spaces like hangars would need to be split into several areas with different floor orientations.

Comment: It is good to see that they spend wisely their money when building a death star.

Comment: Actually, this is a remarkably good answer.

Comment: I like this one. Purely for the practical ramifications listed.

Comment: On the edge of a 150 km-diameter sphere, this effect would be so small as to be unnoticeable: assuming a room 10 meters wide, built to follow the curvature, the center would be a sixth of a millimeter higher than the edge. Of course the effect gets larger as you move toward the center. But wasn't the middle of the Death Star hollowed out to serve as a power station anyway?

Comment: @BlueTrin I attended the University of Sheffield, and according to Wikipedia its [Arts Tower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arts_Tower) was originally designed to be cylindrical. They changed it to a cuboid when they worked out the cost of bespoke furniture to account for the curved walls. I figured a spherical "building" would be even worse!

Comment: @Warbo: sorry I was trying to be funny :), you bring a very good point.

Comment: @David Z's answer is a beautiful example of demolishing an entire academic argument with one simple sentence.

Comment: It could still be the case that the artificial gravity generators don't work well if they not oriented the same way.    Presumably they generate a field and this would overlap with any other gravity generators near by.   How does this work near the middle?    Do we even know if gravity generation in Star Wars is very local (e.g. deck plating) to ship wide via some large structure, say in the middle or embedded in the hull?

Comment: @Contango what do you mean? A sixth of a millimeter is perfectly noticeable and Warbo's argument would apply to the power station too. As far as I can see DavidZ's comment is meaningless.

Comment: @Warbo Why am I not surprised that the Arts Tower was subject to late design decisions.

I've been in few buildings that worried me more than when the Arts Tower was swaying in the wind...

Answer (score 80):

**The Death Star's natural gravitational field would be exceedingly weak.**

The Death Star was described as a "small moon" in Star Wars; Wikipedia lists the first Death Star's diameter as 140 to 160 kilometers.  A large moon like ours, 3500km of solid rock, only produces a gravitation field 17% of Earth's at its surface.  The Death Star, besides being much smaller than our Moon, is also mostly hollow, the reason being that you don't build something that big unless you really need the interior space.  The Death Star at its surface would not have a gravitational field of even a thousandth that of Earth, and the field would decrease as you moved into the interior of the station.  Given the weak field, there's nothing to be gained by orienting the floors relative to it.

**A radial orientation means all windows are skylights.**

If you're lucky enough to have a window office in the Death Star, it would be much nicer if you could sit in your executive chair and look out at the stars without craning your neck.  But if the floor is always pointed toward the center of the station, then the windows out are necessarily on the ceiling.  The Emperor seemed to prefer normal windows.

[image: emperor, vader, luke look out window at the stars]

Comment: This is a good point, but it would still be easier to orient "down" toward the center even with a weak gravitational field. Artificial gravity in the same direction could be weaker by the amount of the natural gravity, whereas artificial gravity in a different direction would also have to compensate for the natural gravity (even if it is relatively weak).

Comment: @Null is right. We orient down to the centre on our own space stations as best as we can, and our stations have nothing on the Death Star. That's why the decision to not do so can only be explained by the use of non-spin artificial gravity in the *Star Wars* universe.

Comment: It's good to see that the engineering decisions of the Death Star depend mostly on interior design considerations (windows on the walls, please!) :-)

Comment: If you're supreme evil emperor of the universe, I think you automatically reserve the right to make quirky design choices

Comment: I must be missing something. Why would the gravity get weaker as you moved into the interior of the structure?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Well, I mean, there's this little hole. It was kind of an aesthetic choice by the architect. And if you shoot a laser into this whole, the station blows up.

Comment: @Wlerin, as you move closer to the center, you leave some of the mass behind, which now pulls the other way, so it starts to cancel out. As you get to the center, the mass fully surrounds you from every direction and the gravity force fully cancels out. Amazingly, you can easily prove using Gauss law that *anywhere* inside the void of an ideal hollow sphere, no matter how thick or thin, the gravity force from the shell cancels out completely and it has to be exactly zero (Newton proved this first, the hard way, with calculus).

Comment: @Wlerin to piggyback off of Euro's answer, if you were able to visit the absolute center of the Earth without dying, and it were hollow, then you would find yourself perfectly suspended (weightless) in air; gravity from all the "Earth" around you would be pulling at you in equal amounts. The same thing would happen in the Death Star, if it had the same kind of gravity. People on the outer edge might be able to walk, but people on the 2nd level from the center would be able to leap hundreds of feet in a single bound!

Comment: @EuroMicelli Does that apply *within* the shell of the sphere, though? All the discussions I can find only consider the outer and inner surfaces, not between them.

Comment: @Wlerin, no it doesn't apply to a point within the shell. The Gauss method requires deep symmetry and that a certain imaginary surface that touches the point must contain no mass inside. That surface doesn't exist for a point within the shell. In fact, on such place you would feel the same gravity as if the shell were split in two layers (one shell above you, one below), and the layer above you were removed. The shell above you contributes no net gravity (by the same Gauss argument), but the shell below does.

Comment: @Euro, Weightlessness at the center of the theoretical radial Death Star assumes uniform distribution of mass.

Comment: I don't think you could see stars through your office window on the Death Star, could you? Too much glare from the sun & fluorescent lights.

Comment: @BrianS, yes. Strictly speaking it doesn't need to be uniform, just spherically symmetrical (the mass density can vary, but it must only depend on the radius). It also requires that the sphere be the only source of gravity in the Universe, to maintain the symmetry requirements. That's why I said "ideal sphere". I tried to keep it short :-)

Comment: Note that the Emperor's throne room is at the top of a tower on the north "pole" of the Death Star, so presumably it would function the same either way independently of the Death Star's gravity orientation.

Comment: Isn’t the picture supposed to depict the view from [this structure](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130404020446/starwars/images/5/52/EmperorsTower-ROTJ.png) and thus not affected by Death Star’s structure?

Comment: "The Death Star, besides being much smaller than our Moon, is also mostly hollow, the reason being that you don't build something that big unless you really need the interior space." -- I wonder how much of the Death Star's interior is actually hollow (and perhaps habitable), and how much is made up of machinery to support the primary weapon. I have no idea how that machinery would work, but it seems plausible that it might have to be fairly dense. Propulsion systems might also account for a lot of space and mass.

Comment: If the Death Star was 50% solid matter, with all the solid matter of the density of lead, and 75 km in diameter, its mass would be 10^19 kg, and the gravitational acceleration at the surface would be about 0.1 m/s^2 or about 0.01 g.

Comment: @MiloPrice - "Note that the Emperor's throne room is at the top of a tower on the north "pole" of the Death Star...". That must have been a *long* trip for Luke with his creepy old man in the elevator. :P

Comment: I'm not sure if someone mentioned before, but the natural gravity of a Death Star depends more on the mass of the Death Star itself, not so much on the size.

Comment: I tried to estimate gravity for the death star, assuming the same density as the empire state building (another large man-made object people occupy). A 160 km death star gives about 5% of 1% of earth gravity. A 900 km death star gives about 2.5%. http://i.imgur.com/72C0YSb.png

Comment: *"If you're lucky enough to have a window office in the Death Star..."* Dunno if I'd call it lucky, what with the office having a 2:2 track record of being blown up... ;-)

Answer (score 20):

The design you're describing is very similar to that of [Centrepoint Station](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Centerpoint_Station), a large space station in the [Corellian system](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Corellian_system). Its construction pre-dates the invention of [artificial gravity without spin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Artificial_gravity_generator) in the *Star Wars* universe. By the time the Death Star is constructed, however, artificial gravity is commonplace. It makes sense, therefore, for the Death Star to use the pre-existing and commonly used artificial gravity convention used in all other Imperial construction, rather than pursuing a radically different design philosophy, no matter how much sense it might make from a physics background.

Answer (score 9):

All the above answers are good, but I'd also like to add that with a radial layout, only one layer would be on the surface of the station: a single shell surrounding the entire sphere.  Obviously you could divide that "surface level" into different zones for different operations, but it would quickly become unwieldy to have, for example, a docking station where ships come down from the roof and then you have to go down a series of floors for different levels of operation.

Much better to have a sphere with flat levels equivalent to latitude, so that the re-supply docks can be at a certain latitude while the military docks can be elsewhere, etc.  With a flat level structure every floor has a ring of surface contact around the edge, allowing for more efficient transfer of objects and ships between the interior of the station and the outside, and easier localization of different departments and facilities along a single floor of the facility.

Answer (score 7):

Given fixed density, gravitational acceleration at the surface of a spherical body is proportional to the radius of the body (mass goes up as the cube of radius, but gravity falls off with the square of distance from the center of gravity).

Thus, the gravity of a solid rock Death Star of the same density as Earth's moon would be on the order of 0.007 Earth gravities at the outer edge, and decreasing as you go deeper. The Death Star isn't solid rock; a large fraction of its volume filled with nitrogen and oxygen gas, hundreds of times less dense.

This means the artificial gravity generators still have to do more than 99.3% of the work even if you orient floors center-ward. The Empire was obviously not concerned with engineering efficiencies of that order.