# Why is the Death Star spherical?

Tags: star-wars

We have already [established](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/68815/17377) why the design of the Death Star does not require a gravitational field emanating radially from its center (and thanks for all the great answers).

But then, why does it have to be spherical? With a gravitational field running along a preferred direction, would it not make more sense to make it, say, cubical so that every level optimizes the amount of interior space relative to the amount of exterior shell around it?

Comment: But then how could it be confused for, and possibly ignored as, "a small moon"? I theorize it was designed to be as close to a lunar disguise as could be made.

Comment: @wbogacz - It's intended to be invulnerable to everything but another death star. Why would they need the element of surprise at all?

Comment: "...optimizes the amount of interior space relative to the amount of exterior shell..." means spherical. Since we tend to like rooms to be square and not arcs, though, the practically usable space might be lower in a sphere.

Comment: @TimS.: I think you missed the words "every level". For *each level* to optimize its interior-space-to-exterior-shell ratio, you'd actually want a *cylinder*.

Comment: A sphere is the worst defensive shape (see my answer below). I can only assume non-defensive considerations overruled defensive ones.

Comment: @TimS.  For a 150km sphere the fraction of rooms that need to have round walls/ceilings/flooring is negligible.

Comment: One thing to consider is the difference between an operational (even partially operational) vs a non-operational station.  In the early stages of construction, when the entire vessel is effectively unpowered, a spherical station is likely the only option for gravitational reasons.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I don't think they'd need any curved surfaces, honestly.  The volume where the curvature would be highest, at the core, is completely given over to machinery.  The shells above that would be sufficiently large that they could be made locally flat without any real issues.  Very long hallways and roads would curve downward, but that's not really a negative quality, it's just unusual for us.

Comment: They really should have retcon'd the diameter to be [396 km](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimas_(moon)).

Comment: @NickT By far one of the more fun recommendations on this page.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Not to bring too much reality to canon here or anything... but from the perspective of a military engineer (me -- 6 years 18C):

While a sphere is indeed the shape most optimized to contain the largest volume in the smallest surface area, this is actually the worst possible thing you can do for a defensive structure. The best defensive structures look like triangles (when undermanned), and grow *extrusions* as resources become available (as in, angular extensions ending in a point). So a defensively optimized Death Star would look more like a giant version of the 1980's rendition of Superman's babyhood spaceship than a ball.

The reason for this is it concentrates defensive fields of fire, observation and clearly defines the line of final protective fire. At the same time this shape forces an approaching enemy into increasingly tight channelized zones within which obstacles, traps and interdiction devices can be placed, and such spaces can even serve as advantaged terrain within which to fight entire self-contained battles against the channelized enemy without threatening any worse than a breach to three extrusions at a time. These extrusions  should be internally segregated from anything critical (so extrusions might house perishable storage, storage for dangerous stuff that might burn/explode, non-critical living areas, etc. while the entire extrusion should be only a conceptual "drawbridge" away from isolation from the next inner defensive wall/barrier).

Imagine being a gunner on a ball-shaped Death Star: your field of fire is greater than 180 degrees in *three* dimensions. Its you against literally more than half the universe. In addition, even at the Death Star's vast size, an enemy could approach quite close and still be below your meaningful horizon. The solution to this is to place defenses on towers, which now exacerbates the situation of marking a field of fire. In real life we try to limit a defender's field of fire to less than 60 degrees in two dimensions (ideally ~30 degrees along the horizon, or buttressed against a wall on one side in the case of a vertical field of observation), and ideally have the defenders shooting where one limit of fire is the wall of the defensive structure itself and the other only slightly angled from it -- this gives them a meaningfully narrow field of observation and vastly increases the chances of them firing in enfilade. The idea with fast moving targets like fighter craft is to have the enemy fly into your shots, not to try and track their course. This is a *lot* easier if their path of egress is limited by physical barriers instead of having over 180^3 degrees of freedom.

In a fight against small, fast-moving, highly-maneuverable fighters this is optimal -- it deprives them of their speed and agility. In a fight against large cruisers it would probably also be an ideal layout because scoring a critical, large hit would be difficult, as everything important is deeply nestled within the prongs, drastically limiting the opportunity for a meaningful hit on target for a capital ship.

The star-like shape I am describing is actually the way that firebases (well, when a competent engineer is involved -- not always the case), patrol bases (at least when real infantry do it), and even castles and coastal defenses going back hundreds of years have been built. "Round" is a maximally taxing shape from a defensive engineers point of view and an attacker's dream come true.

All that said, I doubt that anybody involved in the production of Star Wars was a infantryman, a military engineer, or had ever taken machine guns 101. To stay in-universe and give a reason, however, requires some pretty creative thinking. Looking at the project from a *cost* point of view, a sphere might be quite attractive. Looking at it from an energy conservation point of view this may also be the case, as extrusions would massively aggravate the amount of energy required to overcome rotational inertia and actually aim the thing (all that angular momentum stuff you learn about in school -- not that Star Wars seems to pay this much mind elsewhere). In short, anything other than a spherical Death Star would be very costly to aim.

Could cost + maneuver budget + the Emperor's self perception of invincibility* be enough to motivate a spherical design? I don't know -- but from a defensive point of view, it is a critical blunder. But we already knew the design was flawed the first time we saw Luke blow the thing up in an X-Wing!

(* This point being debatable with regard to the Emperor himself, maybe, but certainly stands for the sneering officer that Darth Vader choked out in the briefing room -- and I assume this reflected the majority opinion of fleet officers everywhere. Wouldn't you feel proud to thump your chest if you had a Death Star? Even a round one?)

Anyway, it bears mentioning that the Death Star was not a defensive weapon in concept.

Edit: Adding a few references. There is no online version of the old A-Camp manual (Pappy Jones!), but the above (and a thousand other related) issues are discussed there at length.

- [Star fort on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_fort)
- [Arctic Patrol Base Operations](http://www.wainwright.army.mil/nwtc/Classes/Slides/Cold_Weather/Arctic%20Patrol%20Base%20OperationsV1.pdf) (Skip to Slide 7)
- [Patrol Base Operations - Mississippi College](http://www.mc.edu/rotc/files/8013/1471/9558/MSL_202_L05a_Patrol_Base_Operations.pdf) (Skip to Slide 4, note placement and orientation of machine guns)

**Edit:** Thoughts on deflectors/shields prompted by a comment from @RonLugge :

I am not a Star Wars canon expert, but I'll make two big assumptions here

1. That shields cost less than the things they protect (otherwise they would not be cost-effective)
2. That shields cannot be projected through one another (we never see layered shielding in the movies)

If these two assumptions hold then a star shape is considerably better than a sphere. The outer shield of the Death Star still serves its original purpose and shape. Following the two basic defensive rules that 1) a single layer of defense is no defense, and 2) unmanned obstacles are not obstacles, it is absolutely necessary to physically harden the outer portions of the extended spikes with ablative material*, and most critically, place deflector shields in layers between and among the defensive extensions. This not only makes attacking the Death Star an onion-cutting problem for a large scale fleet attack (the main scenario against which the Death Star's original defenses were supposedly designed), but also provides the Death Star the chance to literally parcel up a large fighter swarm attack into trapped segments which are much easier to deal with.

Considering the immense size of the Death Star and the (almost ludicrous closeness of Star Wars space battles), though, the star-shape would actually be able to physically disrupt formations of capital ships as well. I didn't consider this until I saw an image of a super star destroyer drawn to scale against the Death Star -- at 19km in length, the super star destroyer looked positively tiny.

(* Ablation being drastically improved by the dynamic expanded surface area of any shape *other* than a sphere -- which is why we don't buy spherical heat-sinks for our computers.)

The main deflector now becomes much more than a simple shield: it can now be used as a tactical element of enemy formation disruption by selectively switching it off to deliberately permit a portion of the attacking formation to enter, and then turning it back on to cut them off from assistance.

Gauging the optimal size of an enemy formation to attack is a tactical issue, but this is the basic idea behind disintegrating tank and infantry defenses, use of double-sided sally ports and the like in ground warfare. A similar technique has been used in real aerial battles, where ground-to-air defenses are deliberately left hidden and unengaged until a selected portion of the enemy formation has crossed them (the fighter screen advancing ahead of a bomber formation, for example) to deliberately isolate a "manageable" formation from the main support body and disrupt the main attack (the bombers) or strip it of its air-to-air support.

Comment: Death Pyramid just doesn't have the same ring to it.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Indeed!

Comment: Great response! I had the same thoughts but you beat me to it. Actually, I think not a pyramid but a regular tetrahedron would be the optimal shape if volume of building material used is the limiting factor. The cube presents more edges to an attacker, but a tetrahedon with the same volume has *longer* edges. The tetrahedron also presents more surface area to an attacker than a cube given equal volumes.

Comment: What about optimal placement of the turbolasers? I'm thinking crowd every spare foot along the tetrahedron edges with turbolasers - any spare turbolasers left over stick on extrusions (towers) along the edges as you mentioned.

Comment: @zxq9 Just a point, but wouldn't the value of your defenses only realy be apparent in traditional ground based combat? The death star is in space = full 3D combat, there is no such thing as terrain to consider in space. A star fort works great when you have to approach on the same x,y coordinates as the walls less so when approaching from above/underneath is just as easy

Comment: @RobertF We want as spikey a shape as possible, no smooth sides. The optimal placement of weapons is on the tips, innermost corners, and along outer ridges (as you mention) and innermost ridges. This provides a complete wall of fire from and to any direction. Rate of fire, rivetment durability and (especially in the Death Star's case) effective range would dictate the optimal placement of weapons by type (and often not in an intuitive way). What you *don't* want is a gun sitting on a flat or convex surface or pointing perpendicularly out from a wall.

Comment: @Culyx The positive aspects of a star fort still apply in space: one of the problems with small fighters is their maneuver, which a shape limits by *creating terrain* specifically because space lacks this. In terms of armor and shielding VS mundane/ablative surface distribution a complex, spikey texture is still *vastly* superior to a sphere (enormously so, when considering energy weapons!). Consider the deliberate angularity of tank armament.

Comment: @zxq9 Agreed in terms of having a spiky surface, but the larger or more numerous the protrusions the larger the cost/material requirements... In that regard I do agree with your assessment of "not built for defense" but I would view it as a result of cost not oversight

Comment: @zxq9 - I'm not sure a spiky surface is better than smooth as long as you have guns mounted along the edges of the polyhedron. A spiky surface would create valleys and hollows in the surface which an enemy vessel could occupy to minimize exposure to enemy firepower. The star forts were also built to concentrate fire on enemy troops assaulting the walls. In ship-to-ship combat in space that may not be necessary.

Comment: @RobertF Guns go on the innermost parts first, not the outermost. There is a whole series of courses on this, actually -- I used to teach them. The reasons apply more strongly to a 3D battlefield than a 2D one.

Comment: What does `6 years 18C` mean? Some kind of military ranking?

Comment: *All that said, I doubt that anybody involved in the production of Star Wars was a infantryman* - well, for starters, producer (and creative genius) Gary Kurtz served as a cameraman in the USMC in Vietnam. And it was made less than ten years after the Vietnam war and just a bit more than 30 after WW2. I'm positive many of the staff had been in active military service at some point. That said, I don't think they ever really wanted to make Star Wars a realistic movie.

Comment: @SáT "Military Cameraman" (even a Marine) is not the same as "infantryman". One knows the tools of filmography and is not confused by the paraphernalia of war, the other is a specialist in the application of mass violence and knows that war is work. Folks who have never worked in combat arms (infantry, artillery, combat engineer, etc.) are usually shocked at the large body of specialized trade knowledge even a small unit (fire team or squad) represents. Its not walking around looking cool with guns.

Comment: @SJuan76 "18C" is a Military Occupational Specialty code. Folks familiar with the US Army will know what that means, folks who aren't tend to not understand the distinction between different military specialties in the first place (see the previous comment, for example), which is why I wrote it that way. I didn't want to distract from the subject in the main text body by mentioning a specific job title that some folks get excited about. (Also, my little shout out to Pappy Jones is something only other 18C's would get, but would be significant to them if any happen to read this.)

Comment: Have you considered how the presence of deflector screens (shields) might adjust the consideration?  A minimized surface area may become more important under those circumstances.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Well technically the way it actually IS shaped it should be called _Death Ball_. If I understand zxq9 correctly, they should have shaped it like they named it, like a 3D-Star-shape....

Comment: @RonLugge I edited the answer to add some thoughts on the shape taking deflectors into account. Unfortunately while deflectors are perfectly well accepted handwavium by the audiences, the *immensely* interesting potential for their use as tactical devices and disruptive tools (aside from just "more armor") seems to have been overlooked in the series. Of course, we're really interested in the story, and an overly complex tactical play might detract from that.

Comment: Even a single tetrahedron wouldn't be enough. I think the absolute minimal spikiness would be that of a stellated octahedron ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellated_octahedron ) which would provide basic defensive shapes, which each side able to fire along a neighboring one.

Comment: @Medinoc It is certainly better than a sphere, but I would go a bit farther (there are a few purely exposed external ridges) and say that a defensible shape should exhibit pure stellated extrusion, more like a [great stellated dodecahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_of_great_icosahedron_and_great_stellated_dodecahedron). The more complex question, really, is whether to have the mouth of the main weapon on a tip, replace an entire spine (and have the rear of the main weapon column housed in the opposite spine) or something in-between. Its the whole point of the station, after all.

Comment: What we are really looking for is a defensive scaffold about the core components: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Compound_of_great_dodecahedron_and_small_stellated_dodecahedron.png I think something like this would have been easily within the capabilities of the Empire, considering they managed to build *two* Death Stars.

Comment: Just wait a minute, there. Are you suggesting that the Death Star had a flawed design?

Comment: Soo... You're saying they should have made a Death Star instead of a Death Sphere?

Comment: This is a lot of interesting information, but frankly I'm surprised this it is getting so many upvotes.  There could be very simple explanations for it is sphere shaped.   Maybe the shield generator operates from the center and falls off with distance, and they need as much volume as possible within minimal area.   Maybe the spherical shape is somehow needed for the world-destroying laser to operate....

Comment: ... I'm not trying to give an explanation; I'm saying you have no idea how physics supposedly works for the technology in the film so it's pointless to try to extrapolate from 2D ground-based star-forts to a 3D Death Star with no basis for extrapolation.  There are too different.

Comment: @ThePopMachine If we want to invent maybes from thin air to explain away the spherical shape then we could simply appeal to the idea that ballsy men like Palpatine like large balls. I was providing an answer from a military engineer's perspective (and you somehow have totally overlooked that combined arms warfare is *not* 2D at the tactical level). And anyway, [a spherical shape is *not* required for the main weapon to function](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darksaber). Anyway, I provided a defensive analysis -- and I mentioned the Death Star was not principaly a defensive installation.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Also, the [initial shield generator operated from Endor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Deflector_shield_generator) and was clearly capable of projecting a directed shield wherever it needed. While I'm no expert in Star Wars physics, the basic boundary rules necessary to think through at least a few defensive considerations have been provided by the movies themselves.

Comment: @zxq9:   You are extrapolating from medieval ground-based forts in our universe to space-based world-destroying "moons" in another universe with different physics.  The question is necessarily in-universe.   So your answer offers nothing at all to answer the question.    This is why this should be downvoted.   Not only because it "doesn't apply" but because it "doesn't answer the question" either.   

Q: Why is a 747 shaped like it is?
A: Oooh yippie, I'm a mycologist!   Let's talk about airborne fungal spores for a bit!   They both fly!

Comment: @zxq9:   By the way, you profile says "I despise the groupthink so prevalent on rated-post sites such as this."    But you're entire reputation, 571 as of Oct 7, 2014 comes from this one answer over the last 6 days!   Oh the irony!

Comment: I salute your knowledge of military defense engineering, but you seem to make one important assumption: that the range of the defensive weaponry is exeeding (or at least in the same order of magnitude) as the size of the structure which is defended. -- **This is not the case with the death star!** Just pure speculation on my part, but I'd guess that the turbolaser turrets covering the surface have an effective range of maybe 10km? Defending spiky scructures will become a whole lot more diffictult if a lot of your weaponry is out of range at any given point of attack...

Comment: @fgysin This could certainly be the case. I'm not sure what the max effective range of the turbolasers is supposed to be. If we assume a range of 10km then we still want a (locally) spiky shape, but where extrusions are only about 70% that long. In other words, the whole thing would then look like a ball covered in 4-edged pyramids 7km to a side. Shields projected between the tips would provide local disruption against small fighters, but this does nothing against capital ships. Which begs a question this comment is too short to ask...

Comment: @fgysin The defenses were designed to ward off a frontal assault by a fleet of capital ships. If this is true where are the ion cannons? Why so many short-range lasers at all? So either turbolasers are *much* longer range, the primary defensive weapons are long range but we don't see them in action, or the Empire didn't think things through. Assuming their are longer range weapons scattered about, the spiky shape argument holds once again, as local shields between extrusions could channelize fighters and give the main defensive armaments a chance to function.

Comment: @fgysin Ah, I just [looked it up](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Turbolaser). It appears turbolasers were used for planetary bombardment as well, so the effective range should be at least a few hundred thousand kilometers. This still makes me marvel at the total lack of [point-defense canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Point-defense_laser_cannon) on the Death Star.

Comment: @zxq9 Good point with the small 7km pyramids. But maybe these devices against fighter-scale attack crafts are just not needed because the hull strength and shields of the Death Star are so strong that the additional cost would not be merited. As for long-range capital ship defenses: I think the main Death Star laser beam does a pretty good job here. :) Given time for reloading and aiming this weapon basically ensures a guaranteed capital ship kill every couple of minutes - this must be a very scare scenario when attacking fleets have in the order of dozens of captial ships.

Comment: After thinking for a while, I will select this as the best response, even though there is no explicit answer! If someone ever reaches this far in the replies, please consider upvoting Stephen's comment above :)

Comment: @zxq9 - 
     
Is it really a defensive structure?  I always thought that it was supposed to fly around the galaxy blowing up defenseless planets. Everyone aboard the Death Star I seemed surprised when the rebels attacked it. –

Comment: @WadCheber The purpose of the Death Star was *strategically* offensive, but the structures that surround the main mechanism are *tactically* defensive. For this reason I focused the discussion about its shape on a defensive assessment. It has a broad multi-role capability to serve as a large space dock, invasion staging platform, and independent base station. But the unique thing is the huge weapon, of course. If the only purpose were to blast planets then the [Darksaber](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darksaber) design is vastly superior.

Comment: There are significant downsides to the Death "star" described here. For starters, that is a LOT more surface area to be rendered airtight and radiation shielded. Second, it dramatically increases the lines of communication (personnel/supply transport) within the Death Star. Instead of lateral movement things within these spikes have to move up and down to get to an adjacent spike. Plus these spikes might be more vulnerable to capital ship bombardment, something the DS designers clearly had a concern about. But on the plus side, the cylons listened to you :P

Answer (score 55):

I did some quick math here, everything is rounded to the nearest kilometer.
The internet says that the 1st Death Star was 160 km across, that means it has a radius of 80 km. Therefore it had a volume of 2,144,661 cubic km and surface area of 80,425 square km. If you wanted to build a cube shaped space station that is 2,144,661 cubic km, then it would have a length of 129 km and a surface area of 99,846 square km. The cube would have an extra 19,421 square km of surface area that has to be protected from vacuum, radiation and attack. That is almost a quarter more than the surface area of the sphere. That means they would also need about 24% more turbolasers to provide the same level of coverage. Keep in mind that the inside walls don't need to be air proof or resistant to lasers, only the outside.

Comment: I agree. The ideal defensible solution is one with the lowest surface area to volume ratio, and a sphere beats every other 3d shape.

Comment: Surely a cylinder would be more defensible? You could have overlapping fields of fire running down the entire surface without having to worry about an horizon in every direction

Comment: @Richard I suggest that the cylinder is better suited to protect against attacks from small fighters (that can get in close enough for horizons to matter), but the sphere shape still wins out if its enemy is large and remains at a distance as nearly half the lasers could target the same point in space.

Comment: You're not wrong. Depending on the angle of attack, you could be hidden from up to about 60% of the cylinder's weapons compared to precisely 50% of the sphere's.

Comment: No, a sphere is the worst possible shape for defense. Round == Bad in terms of defense. But the Death Star was not built for defense, I assume.

Comment: @zxq9 I'd really expect you to elaborate on "Round == Bad in terms of defense" to be taken seriously.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I did, in a multi-paragraph answer on this page.

Comment: as a sphere the death star has equal abilities around the entire ship. it has no area more or less defensible. as a craft this big, and relatively slow an entire fleet could attack it and surround it, but no side would be more or less accessible then any of the others. and as i saw above your weapon systems would be able to most effectively cover every surface of the sphere.

Comment: Since turbolasers on the Death Star's surface cannot fire below the horizon, a spherical Death Star produces dead zones along the surface where starfighters can hide from artillery fire. In fact a cubic (or even better, pyramidal) Death Star would maximize defensive power if the turbolasers are concentrated along the edges of the polyhedron. (The star forts in Europe take advantage of this geometry.) Indeed, it looks like the Imperial Star Destroyers were constructed along these lines.

Comment: I think you can see it the other way round: a cube allows for 24% more turbolasers, which means 24% more enemy fighters can be shot down.

Comment: well the borg use cubes, cylinders and spheres. so obviously they know whats up.

Comment: @Richard: "Depending on the angle of attack, you could be hidden from up to about 60% of the cylinder's weapons compared to precisely 50% of the sphere's." Only at asymptotic distances. As fighters get closer, the attacker can hide itself from what approaches 100% of the surface area. A sphere is the worst possible configuration, and a cube would be better.

Comment: Two lines to remember:  "The defenses are built around a large-scale assault", i.e. by capital ships, and "the fighters are so small, they're evading our turbolasers!" (i.e. "we're flinging 5" artillery shells at the fighters, but we keep missing!")

Comment: Thats why I never understood the Borg.

Comment: @DebugErr: understand the Borg, do you not? To be assimilated, prepare you must!

Answer (score 7):

A sphere has an offensive advantage in respect of pointing at a target.  Similar to why gun turrets are round, so that they can be rotated on bearings, the sphere allows for rotation in 3D without excessive angular momentum being created and dissipated.

[image: DeathStar weapon dish]

It would suffice to have two internal rings at right angles within the DeathStar.  Setting one of these in motion would, by conservation of momentum, cause the DeathStar to rotate about that ring's axis but in the opposite direction.  When the ring stops rotating, so would the DeathStar (again because of conservation of momentum).  Two rings allows the weapon dish to be pointed in any direction.

Comment: Your last paragraph (which seems to refer to [**reaction wheels**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_wheel)) is not special regarding spheres, but would apply to any shape so long as it had a symmetric distribution of mass (e.g. a cube or tetrahedron of uniform density). As for your first bit, there are no "bearings" in space, anything will spin freely. The only OK-ish quip is that it it potentially minimizes the [moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) to avoid the "excessive angular momentum being created and dissipated".

Answer (score 2):

Optimal use of space probably wasn't a key feature in the Death Star's design.

From a tactical stand point there are two practical purposes that the Death Star served: the first was to have massive firepower, and the second was to be (practically) indestructible.

Let's assume that the combination of these features required an extremely large structure but did not require any specific shape. At this point there are a few secondary purposes that the Death Star could have been designed for. The first of these, which incited this question, is optimal use as a military base / administrative hub for the Empire. The tactical advantages granted by this usage are probably minimal and already served by other imperial assets. The second purpose is as a symbol of imperial power, in which case form (e.g. looking intimidating) would most likely trump function.

In short the in-universe reason why the Death Star is spherical is probably the same as the creative reason: because somebody thought it looked imposing and that was more important than practicality.

Answer (score 1):

I've always assumed the entire design of both Death Stars was spherical for one reason only, to provide protection for the reactor... Yes the one that gets blown up on each of them and that is located at the center of it.

That reactor is, clearly, the most important and most critical system of the whole ship and thus it make sense to build the whole structure to be able to protect it. By locating it in the center of a sphere shaped structure yo ensure it's the most protected part.

Leaving aside the plot devices that allow for a single torpedo to destroy which doesn't make any sense but that we have to believe for the shake of the story, a spherical  shape is actually a good design decission for protecting a single core source of power equaly.

Note that in a fully finished Death Star, even with shields down and assuming you don't have stupid "route your torpedo through here" exhausts, it is pretty difficult to reach the central core as you would have to go through the outer and inner hull and the whole structure which would demand a big chunk of firepower... And which such a big structure most of it will likely remain active and able to fight back.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Studying Commonalities throughout the Void]

The easiest, most natural form for a liquid to take is a sphere. The force of surface tension pulls to form an equilibrium shape which is spherical. Look at the shape a bubble forms into! With a planet there are different forces at work, but the same result.

The designers of the Death Star knew that their moon sized planet destroyer would need to be built into the shape of a moon, That is to say, if the plan was going to be to build it as big as a moon. You might say they had know choice. Then again you might say, that the Dark lord choose to work with nature, as oppose to the Borg, whom, you might say work to "assimilate" nature. Their Cube craft, would bend and round in on its self as its constant upgrades and "assimilations" reaches the size of a small moon. Thats correct, their Cube would manifest structural implosions as its mass succumb to the natural inclination to become round.

Einsteins explanation of relativity explains why bodies in space of **great mass** form spheres. The fabric of space/time is bent around huge objects. This causes gravity to act uniformly in a sphere. Again, if a rocky planet somehow was made in a cube, there would be tremendous gravitational forces trying to crush it into a sphere!

The Borg Hypercube, larger than their Cube class spacecrafts, are still cubes because they are no where near the size of a moon, planet, or other massive solid object like the Death Star![Examining Commonalities throughout the VOID VERSE.]

As mentioned, any solid object above a certain mass and radius will succumb to the forces of nature and bend in on its self. The self-gravity of the object overcomes the yield strength of even the strongest solid materials of which it is made of. The surface may still be irregular, but overburden pressure causes the rocks deep inside to deform until the planet has a stable spherical shape. For solid bodies, that occurs between 200km and 300km radius, depending on the density and strength of the materials. Dwarf planets, moons and asteroids with radii less than 200km may be more potato-shaped, whereas solid bodies reaching 300km tend to be spherical.

Comment: You could radically improve this answer by substantially editing out all of the irrelevant info.

Comment: Did you read the other question, where it was established that the self-gravity of the Death Star is negligible?

Comment: The Death Star only has a radius of 80km, and it is not a solid object. It is mostly hollow.

Comment: You know, there are [Borg spheres](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Borg_sphere).